# Missing boost::posix_time::to_time_t in Git 1.56 boost repository

Tags: c++, git, svn, boost

I'm wondering why method `boost::posix_time::to_time_t` is missing in Git repository, altought in version 1.55 in SVN repository is available.

Git 1.56 posix_time repo, where `to_time_t` is missing:
https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/master/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/conversion.hpp

SVN 1.55 posix_time repo, where `to_time_t` is correctly available:
http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/date_time/posix_time/conversion.hpp

Link to discussion where to_time_t was added:
http://lists.boost.org/boost-commit/2013/05/46171.php

Are there any alternatives for this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there on the develop branch https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/develop/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/conversion.hpp

Specifically, this commit is relevant:

> Restored to_time_t() function removed by commit 6636f49. 
>    
>   develop
>   commit ae536816ee0a8bf65d1c52dc7d2b548925fb1416
>    1 parent 805bf4d 
>   Lastique authored on May 31

Comment: ok, so it's not intention that this method is missing in 1.56. thanks